# How to get cluster membership from d3heatmap

Tags: r, d3.js, cluster-analysis, htmlwidgets

I have the following code:

```
cormat <- cor(mtcars)
d3heatmap::d3heatmap(cormat,
                     colors=leaflet::colorNumeric("RdYlBu", NULL, reverse=TRUE), 
                     dendrogram = "both",
                     symm=TRUE,
                     k_row = 3, 
                     k_col = 3)
```

Which produces the following figure:

[image]

Notice that I assigned `k_col` and `k_row` (desired number of groups - dendrogram colors) to be 3. My question is how can I automatically extract cluster membership from there?

For example by eye:

```
 Blue: mpg, vs, sec
 Green: gear, am, drat
 Red: carb, hp,disp,cyl
```